# Android Studio TextView fontFamily not working in themes

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, fonts, font-family

I have a TextView in my activity_main.xml, and I want to change its fontFamily attribute. It works in the AppTheme and the AppCompat themes:

[image: working]

However, in other themes like the Material themes, the font family is always set to default:

[image: not working]

Is it that the themes don't support those fonts or I've done something wrong?

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is some text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    app:fontFamily="cursive"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.223" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: are you planning to have multiple themes in your application?
you can try adding any fonts (here)[https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html] and make it available to the whole app with all themes.

Comment: I'm trying to use the material theme with those fonts

Comment: @Caleb  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

try to use both `app:fontFamily` and `android:fontFamily` in your xml

Answer (score 6):

Use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

instead of TextView.

Answer (score 3):

Try to change `extend Activity` to `extend AppCompatActivity` for your activity class. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me, I was changing the font family but no changes in my application when being run on emulator. I ,luckily, removed the usb cable that I was using to install the application, cleared it from recent apps, ran it again and here it was all good. The font family changed to what I set to.